# Extract numbers from a certain string

Tags: python, string, pyautogui

I have this string from the `pyautogui` module:
`mouse_position = "Point(x=535, y=415)"`

I just want to get the x and the y and put them in their own separate variables like `x = 535` and `y = 415` but I don't know where to split the string. I can't see myself splitting them without taking multiple steps.

I tried `ext_int = [int(i) for i in mouse_position.split() if i.isdigit()]` but I noticed that it doesn't work as expected. Maybe there's another way to extract them other than splitting? Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share how exactly you obtain that string? That looks like a `pyscreeze.Point` object's string representation, there might be a more direct way to get x & y from there.

Answer (score 3):

Since these are the only numbers in the string, you can pull them out with a short regex:

```
import re

s = 'mouse_position = "Point(x=535, y=415)"'

[int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+', s)]
# [535, 415]
```

This basically says, find all strings that are made of 1 or more digits. Note, that you will need to determine which is `x` and which is `y` by the order in the string. If it could be `Point(y=415, x=535)` you will need something a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could always pull out the really big gun of text extraction.  Regular expressions:

```
import re 

mouse_position = "Point(x=535, y=415)"

d = re.match("Point\(x=(?P<x>\d+), y=(?P<y>\d+)\)",mouse_position).groupdict()
```

`d` is now :

```
{'x': '535', 'y': '415'}
```

Comment: When i was typing this Mark already answered, but I guess this shows of named expressions which you may or may not find useful in this case :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `slicing`:

```py
s = 'mouse_position = "Point(x=535, y=415)"'
x_s=s.index('x=')+2
x_e=s.index(',')
x = int(s[x_s:x_e])

y_s=s.index('y=')+2
y_e=s.index(')')
y = int(s[y_s:y_e])

#print(f"{x=}, {y=}")
print(x)#535
print(y)#415
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the least python-like code, but it is easy to understand and works really well and extremally fast

```
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

while True:
    original_string = str(pyautogui.position()) #getting the position of mouse
    characters_to_remove = "Point()xy=,:[]''" #characters you want to remove
    new_string = original_string
    for character in characters_to_remove:
        new_string = new_string.replace(character, "")
        a = new_string.split()
        b = np.array_split(a, 2)
        c = str((a[0]))
        d = str((a[1]))

    for character in characters_to_remove:
       x = c.replace(character, "")
       y = d.replace(character, "")
    print(x + ", " + y)
```